# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml'

Tags: android, android-studio

When i want to try the app in Android Studio emulator i got this error:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml'
```

I restarted AS, rebuild, clean the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error and not sure the root cause but I fixed removing the following dependency from build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework:play:1.5.0'
```